# What are the known (possible) sources for Three of Coins?

Tags: destiny

The main guaranteed source of Three of Coins is to purchase them from Xûr on the weekend, where you get 5 Three of Coins for 7 Strange Coins.

I believe there are other ways, could be random, could be guaranteed rewards from quests.

What are the different ways to earn Three of Coins, what sources do exist?

Comment: I believe it may be possible to obtain one or 2 from a drop in crucible.

Answer (score 8):

Three of Coins can be acquired from the nightfall rewards. [The patch from 20 october 2015](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/News?aid=13775) shows that the amount of coins that can drop has been increased, so naturally they drop there. They can't drop anywhere else from what has been documented and as far i know it doesn't drop in the Kings Fall raid.

As a bit of side info, here is a small guide on [Three of Coins](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/3o4nef/guide_to_three_of_coins_3oc/)

Comment: just a note, before the patch you could get ~5 from a nightfall.  Haven't gotten any as a reward since, but if I had to guess you get ~10  if the scale up (doubled in my experience) is the same as strange coins.

Comment: I saw 12 "three of coins" drop last night as the nightfall reward. As well as 15 "strange coins".

Comment: @TravisJ In one nightfall run? ie. 12 three of coins + 15 strange coins? Or was that for two different players? Or was it 12 + 15 total across all 3?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - Those were two different players.

Answer (score 0):

You can get three of coins from Xur but the other way I know is to get them from nightfall rewards, and very occasionally from vanguard strikes.